Compiling Spot-On Encryption Suite Messenger without Qt Creator
I wanted to compile the Spot-On Encryption Suite from a qmake terminal with these commands and steps:
As compiling the Spot-On Encryption Suite requires several steps, including setting up the necessary dependencies as obtaining the source code, and then building the application with qmake.
I tried these following steps to compile the messenger – but probably the usage of the .pro file is much easier – I don’t see what is missing here:

Starting with the prerequisites

Operating System:
Typically, this process is performed on a Unix-like system (Linux, macOS).

Dependencies:
You will need the following dependencies installed on your system:

gcc (GNU Compiler Collection) or another C++ compiler
Qt (usually version 5 or later)
OpenSSL (for cryptographic operations)
qmake (part of Qt)




Steps to Compile Spot-On Encryption Suite

Install Dependencies:

On a Debian-based system (like Ubuntu), you can install the necessary packages with:
sh
Code kopieren
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential qt5-default libssl-dev


On Fedora:
sh

Code kopieren
sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase-devel openssl-devel






On macOS, you can use Homebrew:
sh
Code kopieren
brew install qt openssl




Download Spot-On Source Code:
Typically, the source code is hosted on a version control system like GitHub. You can clone the repository using git.
sh
Code kopieren
git clone https://github.com/textbrowser/spot-on.git


Navigate to the Source Directory:
sh
Code kopieren
cd spot-on


Configure the Build:
Use qmake to generate the Makefile. Ensure that the qmake binary from your Qt installation is in your PATH.
sh
Code kopieren
qmake spot-on.pro


Compile the Application:
Once the Makefile is generated, compile the application using make.
sh
Code kopieren
make


Run the Application:
If the compilation is successful, you should have an executable file (usually named spot-on). You can run it with:
sh
Code kopieren
./spot-on




Troubleshooting which has been checked

Path Issues: Ensure that your qmake and compiler binaries are in your PATH. You might need to specify the full path to qmake if it's not found:
sh
Code kopieren
/path/to/qt/bin/qmake spot-on.pro


Qt Version: Ensure you are using a compatible version of Qt. If you have multiple versions installed, ensure you are using the correct one by specifying its path.

Library Linking: Sometimes, you may encounter issues with linking libraries like OpenSSL. Ensure the libraries are correctly installed, and the paths are properly set.



Example Script:
Here's a simple bash script to automate the above steps on a Debian-based system:
sh
Code kopieren
#!/bin/bash

# Install dependencies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential qt5-default libssl-dev git

# Clone the repository
git clone https://github.com/textbrowser/spot-on.git
cd spot-on

# Configure the build
qmake spot-on.pro

# Compile the application
make

# Run the application
./spot-on

This script above should set up the environment, download the source code, and build the Spot-On Encryption Suite. Adjusting the commands based on my specific system configuration and package manager does not lead to a binary, as the .pro file does:
cache()
doxygen.commands = doxygen spot-on.doxygen
purge.commands = rm -f */*~ *~

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS = doxygen purge
SUBDIRS         = Kernel/spot-on-kernel.pro spot-on-gui.pro
TEMPLATE        = subdirs


Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear (to me at least) what your question is, this post is almost a very informative tutorial blog. This only indications of a question I can see are: "I don’t see what is missing here", but you don't specify why you think something is missing; and this: "does not lead to a binary", which is clearer than the first one, but still vague, because you don't specify what happens, what went wrong, does the script output errors? Does it just run silently and outputs nothing?

I am not a building-tools expert, I just mostly rely on Qt Creator to do that magic for me, so I might just not be understanding your request. But, it would be helpful if you could please elaborate further on what the problem is and what results did you get, so that the experts here can understand the problem and provide clear detailed answers without relying on guesses.

many thanks, terminal compilation worked out for Linux, just Windows was the question, so I installed Qt Creator now. Also to see: the new code release as source release here: https://github.com/textbrowser/spot-on/releases/tag/2024.07.15 - will try also terminal compilation for windows now with that source.

it is not the source, it is the library or ssl probably for windows, see also here the steps: https://github.com/textbrowser/spot-on/blob/master/branches/trunk/Documentation/COMPILING
